# Getting a nullpointer error on my TabHost LayoutInflater

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I'm adding a TabHost to my ListActivity, but my app crashes due to a null pointer error. I added setup () but the null pointer switches to that line of code. I cannot see where I'm wrong. Here is my code:

```
public  TabHost tabHost;


  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
      getListView ().setClickable (false);
      final TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById (android.R.id.tabhost);
       tabHost.setup ();

       tabHost.addTab (createTab(AdListActivity.class, "ad feed",
            "Ad Feed", R.drawable.news_icon ));
       tabHost.addTab (createTab (UserInput.class, "new ad",
              "New Ad", R.drawable.upload_ad));


       tabHost.setCurrentTab (0);
       tabHost.getTabWidget ().getChildAt (0).getLayoutParams ().width = 140;
       tabHost.getTabWidget ().getChildAt (1).getLayoutParams ().width = 140;
  }

    private TabHost.TabSpec createTab(final Class<?> intentClass, final String tag,
      final String title, final int drawable)
  {
      final Intent intent = new Intent ().setClass (this, intentClass);

        final View tab = LayoutInflater.from (getTabHost ().getContext ())
             .inflate (R.layout.tabs, null );
       ((TextView)tab.findViewById (R.id.tab_text)).setText (title);
       ((ImageView)tab.findViewById (R.id.tab_icon)).setImageResource (drawable);

       return getTabHost ().newTabSpec (tag).setIndicator (tab).setContent (intent);
   }


    public TabHost getTabHost() {
       return tabHost;
   }
}
```

Here is my StackTrace:

> 10-21 13:33:37.300  15243-15243/ionictech.com.synchup E/ResourceType﹕
>   Style contains key with bad entry: 0x0101047910-21 13:33:37.400 
>   15243-15243/ionictech.com.synchup W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread
>   exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40aae9d8)10-21 13:33:37.430 
>   15243-15243/ionictech.com.synchup E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{ionictech.com.synchup/ionictech.com.synchup.AdListActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at ionictech.com.synchup.AdListActivity.onCreate(AdListActivity.java:30)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
>               at         android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920) at
>   android.ap
>   p.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)            at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)            at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)            at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)            at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)            at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)            at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)            at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Even after I added the setContentView(), I'm still getting a null pointer error so I'm assuming that the problem is from here :

```
  private TabHost.TabSpec createTab(final Class<?> intentClass, final String tag,
      final String title, final int drawable)
    {
      final Intent intent = new Intent ().setClass (this, intentClass);

     //line:63 final View tab = LayoutInflater.from (getTabHost ().getContext ())
                 .inflate (R.layout.tabs, null );
      ((TextView)tab.findViewById (R.id.tab_text)).setText (title);
      ((ImageView)tab.findViewById (R.id.tab_icon)).setImageResource (drawable);

      return getTabHost ().newTabSpec (tag).setIndicator (tab).setContent (intent); 
    }
```

Here is the new stacktrace:

0-21 15:13:54.444  22327-22327/ionictech.com.synchup E/ResourceType﹕ Style contains key with bad entry: 0x0101047910-21 15:13:54.464  22327-22327/ionictech.com.synchup W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40aae9d8)10-21 15:13:54.464  22327-22327/ionictech.com.synchup E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ionictech.com.synchup/ionictech.com.synchup.AdListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at ionictech.com.synchup.AdListActivity.createTab(AdListActivity.java:63)
            at ionictech.com.synchup.AdListActivity.onCreate(AdListActivity.java:34)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: **"I added setup () but the null pointer switches to that line of code."** : In that case `tabHost` is null which means `findViewById(...)` is failing to find a `TabHost` with the id `android.R.id.tabhost`. Not surprising as you're not calling `setContentView(...)` which you need to do *BEFORE* trying to call `findViewById(...)`

Comment: I did but I'm still getting a null pointer error. I'm guessing at this section: